# How can I monitor the ADO Pipeline Bandwidth dynamically in ASP.Net code?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

We had a problem a while back whereby a website exceeded the link capability between the web server and the database server. This was a consequence of retrieving too much data (more than was strictly necessary) - I'd like to create some kind of monitor in the page life cycle that monitors the size of the data retrieved, and if it exceeds a certain threshold (which is presumably smaller than the network link capability), throw an exception.

It would be simple enough to sprinkle some kind of size evaluator everywhere I retrieved data, but this will quickly fall out of use. I am using Entity Framework, so that may provide another universal hook for this process.

I'm seeing some stuff relating to Provider Statistics, and that's probably the road I'm headed down, but how do I limit this to a single request cycle? I'd really like to be able to identify the page and request when the exception is thrown - this can form a worklist of pages to slim down.